# How to know if all uploads completed within a loop?

Tags: ajax, html, upload, xmlhttprequest

I have a code that works well for sending multiple files via ajax with FormData and XMLHttpRequest;

```
            for (var i=0, j=this.files.length; i<j; i++) {
            file = this.files[i];

            var formdata = new FormData();          
                formdata.append("images[]", file);


            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
                upload = xhr.upload,
                id = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100000));

                upload.addEventListener("loadstart", function(e){
                        showUploadedItem(file, this.id);
                });
                upload.id = id;
                upload.onprogress = function(e) {
                    var done = e.position || e.loaded, total = e.totalSize || e.total;
                    )
                };
                upload.onload = function(e) {

                    if (this.status == 200) {
                      console.log('');
                    }                        
                };
                xhr.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
                    if ( 4 == this.readyState ) {
                        console.log('');
                    }
                };
                xhr.open('post', '<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('url') ?>', true);
                xhr.send(formdata);                    
        }
```

I am sending each file as a new XMLHttpRequest object inside the loop, so I do not know when I'm getting all requests ending.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation for XMLHttpRequest.

There are a couple of options that I can think of. You could use the "loadend" callback for each of them and increment a variable outside of the loop and check for the total amount of requests that were sent in each one. Once the count reaches the total number of requests, you could perform any logic or call a function that would want to call.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FXMLHttpRequest%2FUsing_XMLHttpRequest

Otherwise, setting the async parameter to false would work as well, but then you take a performance hit waiting for each one to finish before starting the others.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your answer, my solution;

```
        var x = 0;
        var lenght = this.files.length;
        for (var i=0, j=lenght; i<j; i++) {

        // code here                   

            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),

             // code here  

                xhr.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
                    if ( 4 == this.readyState && this.status == 200 ) {
                        x++;
                        if(x == lenght) {
                            window.setTimeout( function(){
                                alert('finish');
                             }, 1000 );
                        }
                    }
                };
             // code here
          }
```

Though it is a trivial function, it works.

Comment: You probably don't even need the setTimeout.